# Assigning tags for elapsed in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, syntax, logstash, kibana-4

I have log file that look for example like this:

```
2015-12-05 05:00:51 prefix1_sent 1
2015-12-05 05:00:52 prefix2_sent 2
2015-12-05 05:00:53 prefix1_received 1
2015-12-05 05:00:54 prefix2_received 2
```

I want to find out how much time particular event took. I am using elapsed plugin in logstash like this:

```
....

grok {
        patterns_dir => "path"
        match => { 
            "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP:logtime}, %{EVENT:event}, %{SPLIT:ID}"
        }
    }

filter{
    if [event] == "(.)*sent" {
        if [event] == "prefix1(.)*" {
            kv {
                add_tag => [ "prefix1_sent" ]
            }
        } else if [event] == "prefix2(.)*" {
            kv {
                add_tag => [ "prefix2_sent" ]
            }
    } else if [event] == "(.)*received" {
        if [event] == "prefix1(.)*" {
            kv {
                add_tag => [ "prefix1_received" ]
            }
        } else if [event] == "prefix2(.)*" {
            kv {
                add_tag => [ "prefix2_received" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
filter{
    elapsed {
        start_tag => "prefix1_sent"
        end_tag => "prefix1_received"
        unique_id_field => "ID"
        new_event_on_match => false
    }
}
filter{
    elapsed {
        start_tag => "prefix2_sent"
        end_tag => "prefix2_received"
        unique_id_field => "ID"
        new_event_on_match => false
    }
}

....
```

I am not sure if my syntax of nested if statement is correct of if I understand the use of "kv". I am new to logstash. However I can't find any tag in kibana with this configuration. Where am I making mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments:

- Your nested conditionals are fine.
- Your comparisons using regexps are wrong.  [Use "=~"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.1/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) instead of "==".
- add_tag only works when the underlying filter works.  While your use of kv{} would be fine, you're not actually doing anything with key/values, so it can be confusing.  Most people use mutate{} for things like this.

Those changes would probably get you on track.

For some unsolicited advice, take a look at your workflow.  First, you apply a regexp with grok to make three fields.  Then you regexp one of them again (2-3 times) before you do the add_field.  Try this:

- in the original grok{}, split the event field into the two pieces.  A pattern like this should do it:  %{DATA:event_prefix}_%{DATA:event_verb}
- rewrite your conditionals to be exact matches against these two fields.

Not only is it more "grok-ish", but it would be faster when applied to a large data set.